# Studentized residuals in JSL

Tags: sas-jmp, jsl

How can I add studentized residuals to an already fitted model I have in the JMP table? I have several tables for which I manually open the particular script and do Save Columns--> Studentized Residuals. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Write the model to an object. Like:

```
obj_model = Fit Model(
                   Y()
                   X() etc...
             );
```

Now all functionalities of the model can be executed on the obj_model. So studentized residuals can be called as:

```
obj_model << Studentized Residuals;
```

In case you have multiple tables, you may want to consider using a loop to save the studentized columns, using the snippet above as the body of the loop.

Comment: the thing is I have a fit group with a lot of fit models, and I realized that studentized residuals are functions for fit models and not for fit group. Any workaround?

Comment: could you post some code of what you have done so far?